# django CLI script and database router: cannot import name connections

Tags: django, command-line-interface, sharding

I made a database ruter for `myapp` application
in file `/myproject/myapp/routers.py`

```
class ShardingRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        return None
```

In `settings.py` I have:

```
from django.db import connections
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myproject.myapp.routers.ShardingRouter',]
```

This works well for normal application running through wsgi, but I have one CLI script `/myproject/parser_jobs.py` it is starting with cron or manually from CLI:

```
import os, sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
...
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_some_long_boring_work()
```

now, when i run this script, I'm getting import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hosting/myproject/myproject/parser_jobs.py", line 20, in <module>
    import settings
  File "/hosting/myproject/myproject/settings.py", line 46, in <module>
    from django.db import connections
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.myproject' (Is it on sys.path?): cannot import name connections
```

Looks like it found settings.py, but while importing it fails on `from django.db import connections`. If i comment this string, it works, but without my db router:( I can add `using()` everywhere, but it's not cool.

So, website works good, but cli script fails. Please, help!

---

update: `/hosting/myproject/myproject/parser_jobs.py`  worked good from cli, before I added DB router

`pprint` of `sys.path` in this script:

```
['/hosting/myproject/myproject',
 '/hosting/myproject',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

---

update: wsgi script, website works good with it:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/hosting/myproject'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 1):

my script was in the same folder with `settings.py` 
when I moved it from `/hosting/myproject/myproject/parser_jobs.py` to `/hosting/myproject/parser_jobs.py`  (where in django1.4 manage.py should be) it become working correct.

Also I changed `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")` to `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")`

And now it works!

In previous location `parser_jobs.py` works only without db router